# Per profile Read Write access to bean fields in java based rest WebApp

Tags: java, security, rest, javabeans

## Question

Given a `User` bean stored in database with a lots of fields which is exposed by a rest web app, I want to restrict R/W access to it and it's fields depending on the currently connected user.

Examples:

- Anonymous user can't get anything
- Current user can read and write all fields of it's own record except his nickname (no access at all), userNumber and registration date (read only)
- Admin can read and write all fields of all records
- authenticated users can read every user name and nickname (but their own) and are allowed to change the nickname (except their own)

What is the best way to do it ?

## Extra context

I'm playing a little with [JBoss's Forge 2](http://forge.jboss.org/) and I'm trying to build a web app with an OpenID authentication.
I'll try to hook up OpenId to [apache deltaspike](http://deltaspike.apache.org/) as a security framework, but I can change this if you have a better solution